# C# NetworkStream Write/Read vs Socket Send/Receive?

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

Which one is faster than other? I am building a server-client app but I am not sure which one is faster. I can smoothly send and recive data with both but I want faster communication.

Comment: I believe that Socket is a more basic implementation so you get less out of the box but I don't know that you'll really have that much issues and depending on how you use it, NetworkSteam may have more optimizations built in. Maybe run both and do some test with timers and see what works best for you.

Comment: A Network stream is slightly slower because it takes the TCP data on the TX end and puts in to a stream and Rx removes from the stream.  TCP maximum transfer chunk is 1500 bytes.  But the Network stream eliminates the op from combining the chunks which would be needed when using TCP.  So the speed is of the two are very close.

Comment: You can safely ignore this false statement made by @jdweng: _"the Network stream eliminates the op from combining the chunks"_. All `Stream` objects, including `NetworkStream`, have the same stream-oriented behavior that a TCP `Socket` does, and in all cases there is no automatic _"combining the chunks"_. Whether you use `Socket` or `NetworkStream`, your code needs to be prepared to receive anywhere from 1 byte to the total number of bytes sent but not yet received, and then recombine the bytes received into whatever useful arrangement is required by the program.

Comment: As far as the question of _"which is faster"_ goes, everything you need to know is here: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). The fact is, the computer itself operates at orders of magnitude greater speed than the network connection, so as long as you don't completely screw up the code, any implementation will be "fast enough". If you _"want faster communication"_, get a faster network connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NetworkStream is using sockets internally to operate. You can understanding by looking at the constructor of it in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1).

```
public NetworkStream (System.Net.Sockets.Socket socket);
```

It provides you with methods that you can use to Read/Write to the stream easily.

The `Socket` class on the other hand provide you more control on what kind of data you want to exchange in the network. If you intent on exchanging data via TCP protocol in the network you will probably see no difference in the transfer speed by using Either `Socket` or `NetworkStream`.

If you need to exchange data with faster communication, consider using UDP protocol by using the `Socket` class but keep in mind that the UDP protocol is not connection oriented like TCP and no error checking occurs. As such you can't be sure of the reliability of your data and the guaranteed delivery of them.